# Android: move child layout with SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have implemented a recyclerView inside a SwipeRefreshLayout. Corresponding XML is below.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_news">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

currently swipe looks like this

[image]

i want the background should also move with the swipe like this

[image]

Comment: I think you can achieve this by adding a header view, watching the scroll progress and changing the header's height accordingly. I'm not sure whether there's an easier way.

However, I don't recommend you do this. You should follow Google's guidelines and keep the Swipe to Refresh pattern as it is. Ask yourself, do you really think it will look better with that white space at the top?

Comment: i just wanted to show the user his swipe gesture by scrolling down the list till he keeps pressing it... and release the list back to top when touch is removed.

Comment: You mean swipe feedback. It's good that you thought of this, it's an important UX feature. But the refresh widget already does this. The user can [swipe, release and even reverse the swipe to cancel](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/swipe-to-refresh.html).

Comment: You should look for the source code of the old SwipeToRefreshLayout (support library before android 5.0 release). In the old versions the behavior of the swipe was implemented like you want, the background also moved with the swipe. So I think you should try to merge the new and the old versions of the SwipeToRefreshLayouts and you can achive this.